# UICollectionViewCell dont see Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUQAM.png)In my iPhone app, I have 170 images. I add these images into a `UICollectionView`. It shows 170 cells but they are empty.

#### My code:

`cell.imageCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

#### The debugger says:

> Code will never be executed

```
UICollectionViewCell have @property * imageCell
```

How can I fix this?

#### My Code:

```
   - (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSMutableArray * tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i <170; i++) {
        [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]];
    }
    self.imagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

    for (int j = 0 ; j < [self.imagesArray count]; j++) {

        UIImageView * image =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        image.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:j];
    }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.imagesArray count];
}

    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString * inditifiner = @"Cell";

    MFCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:inditifiner forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;


    cell.imageCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using:

```
   cell.imageCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

to load the images!! But it is wrong!!! `imageNamed` functions expects image name in form of string but not as object!!!

And for the code never executed error, you might have placed the some code after the `return` statement!!!!

try to do it like this:

```
     cell.imageCell.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

As images are stored in the array as objects , you can directly use the above stmt!!!

Also in your layout subview method, you are missing the closing } after the second loop.

And the second loop makes no sense

```
   for (int j = 0 ; j < [self.imagesArray count]; j++) {

    UIImageView * image =[[UIImageView alloc] init];  
    image.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:j];  //this doesn't show anything as image view  is not the subview of any view
    }
```

This doesn't do anything except its a wastage of memory!!!

The first loop:

You are storing the images in an array with the names 1,2,3,.....170 without any extensions.This is fine in case you are storing the image in the assets folder!!

```
   for (int i = 0; i <170; i++) {
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]]];
}
```

Make sure you really have the 170 images named 1,2,3,....170 in your assets.

If they all have the png as extension, and they are not in assets, you should

```
    for (int i = 0; i <170; i++) {
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i.png]]];   //if it is jpg....it should be i.jpg
}
```

Finally make sure, you connect the outlet of imageCell properly for your collection view in the IB!! If it is not an outlet, make sure you add it properly with proper frame to your cell!!!!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <170; i++) {
    [tempArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i.png]]];
}` it's work!!         you say  `NSString *imageName = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`I try, debagger say you  Code will never be executed

Comment: yes, you need to do cell.imageCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

Comment: I try your code,but debagger 
again say Code will never be executed

Comment: One second ok?,I tell my TeamView

Answer (score 0):

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString * inditifiner = @"Cell";

  MFCollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:inditifiner forIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;

  cell.imageCell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

  return cell;

}

ln this method you should delete first  return cell